# Exception "Wrapped java.lang.IllegalStateException: zip file closed " by using new com.mirth.connect.client.core.Client(url);

Tags: java, mirth

my code here:

```
function MsgReceivedInPastHourchannelId,connectorID, status) {

 
var client = new com.mirth.connect.client.core.Client('https://127.0.0.1:443/');
 
try{
   var loginStatus = client.login('userID', 'psw');
} catch(ex) {
    client.close();
   throw 'Unable to log-on the server , Error: ' + ex.message;
}


 
var filter = new com.mirth.connect.model.filters.MessageFilter;
var calendar = java.util.Calendar;

var startDate = new calendar.getInstance();
var endDate = new calendar.getInstance();

..
.. logic to set start/end date
..

filter.setStartDate(startDate);
filter.setEndDate(endDate);
 

var statuses = new java.util.HashSet();
var Status = com.mirth.connect.donkey.model.message.Status;

var list = Lists.list().append(connectorID);


var metricStatus =  Status.SENT;

statuses.add(metricStatus);
filter.setStatuses(statuses);
filter.setIncludedMetaDataIds(list) ;

var nCount =client.getMessageCount(channelId, filter); 
client.close();
return nCount 
}
```

reference :
[Mirth getMessageCount using Javascript not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64505879/mirth-getmessagecount-using-javascript-not-working?newreg=b8e320f5b6c945b3a0777e333197f467)

Mostly it works fine, but it randomly throw exception at line number 218, this is

```
 var client = new com.mirth.connect.client.core.Client('https://127.0.0.1:443/')
```

anyone have experience or solution to get rid of such error:

```
[2021-06-30 02:00:02,000]  ERROR  (com.mirth.connect.connectors.js.JavaScriptDispatcher:193):
 Error evaluating JavaScript Writer (JavaScript Writer "Submit Hx channel status to DataDog" on channel 1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx4).

com.mirth.connect.server.MirthJavascriptTransformerException: CHANNEL:
    ChannelStatus-Poller-CountCONNECTOR:
    Submit Hxchannel status to DataDogSCRIPT SOURCE:
    JavaScript WriterSOURCE CODE:
     218: var client = new com.mirth.connect.client.core.Client('https://127.0.0.1:443/') 221: // log on to the server222: 

try{LINE NUMBER:    218 DETAILS:


    Wrapped java.lang.IllegalStateException: zip file closed

    at a7fa25a9-af95-4410-bb4f-f4f08ae0badb:218 (MsgReceivedInPastHour)

    at a7fa25a9-af95-4410-bb4f-f4f08ae0badb:1013 (doScript)
    at a7fa25a9-af95-4410-bb4f-f4f08ae0badb:1033
    at com.mirth.connect.connectors.js.JavaScriptDispatcher$JavaScriptDispatcherTask.doCall(JavaScriptDispatcher.java:184)
    at com.mirth.connect.connectors.js.JavaScriptDispatcher$JavaScriptDispatcherTask.doCall(JavaScriptDispatcher.java:122)
    at com.mirth.connect.server.util.javascript.JavaScriptTask.call(JavaScriptTask.java:113)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: zip file closed
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.ensureOpen(ZipFile.java:686)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$200(ZipFile.java:60)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipEntryIterator.hasNext(ZipFile.java:508)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipEntryIterator.hasMoreElements(ZipFile.java:503)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile$JarEntryIterator.hasNext(JarFile.java:253)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile$JarEntryIterator.hasMoreElements(JarFile.java:262)
    at org.reflections.vfs.ZipDir$1$1.computeNext(ZipDir.java:30)
    at org.reflections.vfs.ZipDir$1$1.computeNext(ZipDir.java:26)
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:141)
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:136)
    at org.reflections.Reflections.scan(Reflections.java:240)
    at org.reflections.Reflections.scan(Reflections.java:204)
    at org.reflections.Reflections.<init>(Reflections.java:129)
    at org.reflections.Reflections.<init>(Reflections.java:170)
    at org.reflections.Reflections.<init>(Reflections.java:143)
    at com.mirth.connect.client.core.Client.<init>(Client.java:176)
    at com.mirth.connect.client.core.Client.<init>(Client.java:143)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor159.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.newInstance(MemberBox.java:159)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaClass.constructInternal(NativeJavaClass.java:266)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaClass.constructSpecific(NativeJavaClass.java:205)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaClass.construct(NativeJavaClass.java:166)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1525)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:815)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:109)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:405)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3508)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.InterpretedFunction.exec(InterpretedFunction.java:120)
    at com.mirth.connect.server.util.javascript.JavaScriptTask.executeScript(JavaScriptTask.java:150)
    at com.mirth.connect.connectors.js.JavaScriptDispatcher$JavaScriptDispatcherTask.doCall(JavaScriptDispatcher.java:149)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: [tag:java] and [tag:javascript] are very different things

Comment: `function MsgReceivedInPastHourchannelId,connectorID, status) {`

Could you please put the correct, compileable code into your question?

Comment: Actually this is Javascript code in MirthConnect environment( powered by Rhino engine), that's why javascript code can re-use Java Jar.  this function is not Java code.

Comment: Please close this topic, issue could not be solved in Mirth connector Admin environment, to solve this issue, I used DB query instead.

Comment: Have you tried using API call to get the message count instead of trying to access mirth java library?

Comment: @vibin tkx for info, it is actually count in channel level, what i need is connector level, issue solved by directly access DB.

Answer (score 0):

Issue could not be solved in Mirth connector Admin environment, to solve this issue, I used DB query instead.

go to Mirth DB, you can find related tables and it is more safe to query such DB.

The reason not to invoke,
answer from Mirth slack general channel,
"When using the Client class you're pretty much looping back to the server, since all the code is executed on the server anyways."

so always didn't  com.mirth.connect.client.core.Client class in Mirth code.

Issue closed.